# Epoch time difference when dates vary not showing correct value

Tags: postgresql, epoch

```
SELECT
 r.order_id
,c.order_time
,r.pickup_time
,EXTRACT(epoch FROM (r.pickup_time - c.order_time) / 60) AS diff
FROM runner_orders1 r
JOIN customer_orders1 c ON c.order_id = r.order_id
WHERE distance != 0;
```

| order_id | order_time | pickup_time | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 18:05:02 | 2020-01-01 18:15:34 | 10.533333 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 19:00:52 | 2020-01-01 19:10:54 | 10.033333 |
| 3 | 2020-01-02 23:51:23 | 2020-01-03 00:12:37 | 21.233333 |
| 3 | 2020-01-02 23:51:23 | 2020-01-03 00:12:37 | 21.233333 |
| 4 | 2020-01-04 13:23:46 | 2020-01-04 13:53:03 | 29.283333 |
| 4 | 2020-01-04 13:23:46 | 2020-01-04 13:53:03 | 29.283333 |

Here is my above sql output if you see when the timestamp days differ , the value is not correct. Please check and help.

```
 3 | 2020-01-02 23:51:23 | 2020-01-03 00:12:37 | 21.233333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning *exactly* the correct results (at least to the 6 decimal digits). The problem seems to stem from your expectations. Apparently, you are looking for `diff` to be minuets and seconds, however, this is not what you are getting. By extracting epoch and dividing by 60 your results are in minuets and fractional part of a minuet. In the selected the difference in time between `pickup_time` and `order_time` is 21:14 (min:sec) the result returned turns out to be `21:13.99998` (min:sec.fractional seconds). This is just another reason using epoch is not really a good practice (see [Epoch Mania](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/) for others).  
Correct the result by just subtracting the dates (you are already doing so). This gives the result as an interval in *Hours:Minuets:Seconds*. For your example it returns `00:21:14` (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZhMjwp5K))

```
select r.order_id
     , c.order_time
     , r.pickup_time
     , r.pickup_time - c.order_time as diff
  from runner_orders1 r
  join customer_orders1 c on c.order_id = r.order_id
 where distance != 0;
```